# How to greet in English formally?

Tags: phrases, greetings

I've been studying English for 1 year and I'm good at it. Anyway, I would like to know how to greet in some ways.
I greet in 2 ways usually:

- Hi, What's up?/How are you?/What's about you? Not bad, You/I'm not good/I 'm very good. (Informal)
- Hello, How are you? I'm good, thanks, and you? (Formal)

Are there different ways to greet formally? I would like someone list me some ways most common to greet formally (Example: When you're speaking to your boss or teacher), thanks!

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for your question. We hope you'll ask more questions and we look forward to helping you. Unfortunately, this question is too broad for our forum, because there are thousands of ways to greet a person. The list would be hundreds of pages in length! (Also: "I'm good, thanks" is **not** formal. A formal response might be: "I am quite well, thank you.")

Comment: I edited my question, I hope It's right now. @P.E.Dant Is it right now?

Comment: The question is posed well, but it is too broad. Please visit the [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and read carefully the section about _subjective questions._

Comment: I did  it, I think It's on because "inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”", I think everyone can answer without a too long question. Anyway, thanks! I will read Help Center soon.

Comment: In addition to _hello_, there are also _good morning, good afternoon,_ or _good evening_ (depending on the time of day).

Comment: Can I use "night" like "good night'? In Italian we do, Is possible do it in English too?

Comment: "Good evening" is more formal and can be used as a greeting or in parting. "good night" means you are saying goodbye. "Hello" is neutral. A formal greeting **to a new acquaintance only** in almost any circumstance is: "How do you do?" (_Piacere_ in Italian.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are various ways to greet or respond back to a greeting in English language, but I'm sure you want the formal method.

Depending on your age and the environment  you may find yourself, you can chose to greet anyone just by saying *Hello*. *Hello* could be the most formal method of greeting in English.

Comment: Hello is neutral. It is certainly _not_ "the most formal method of greeting in English."